# Does 'top' show memory / CPU usage of parallel processes on cluster?

Tags: linux, cluster, top, monitoring

Recently inherited a neglected cluster: I'm trying to do some sanity checks on it. Running a benchmark on node X and then running 'top' shows high cpu usage from mpi processes (as expected), but on node Y top shows 0% usage.

Is this normal? Is there another utility I can use that can monitor system resources correctly on a node?

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal. The 'cluster' I inherited is actually a bunch of boxes connected through an Infiniband switch without any load-sharing, i.e. not a cluster at all.

A useful utility for monitoring cluster load is **ganglia**. Config took a little finnagling, but it works great if you're not already using other cluster management stuff like Conga.